# In Vim, how to avoid having "/*" be treated as comment

Tags: perl, vim, comments, indentation

Vim keeps treating my perl code as comments and the auto indentation does not work.

```
$dump=`cp /local/*.txt .`;
if ($a == 0)
{
    if ($b == 0)
    {
        print "HELLO";
    }
}
```

was formatted as:

```
$dump=`cp /local/*.txt .`;
                  if ($a == 0)
                  {
                  if ($b == 0)
                  {
                  print "HELLO";
                  }
                  }
```

This is because the "/*" in the first line was treated as comment and hence Vim gives up indenting anything afterwards.

I could think of a workaround as:

```
$dump=`cp /local/*.txt .`; #*/;
```

To manually close the comment.

But is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a file extension such as `.c`, and not `.pl`? Change the extension, and the indentation should work as expected.

Comment: To follow up on @TLP's comment, what does `:set filetype?` show in that buffer? That'll let you know if Vim thinks it's a Perl file.

Comment: You could harmlessly escape the `*`:  `$dump = qx!cp /local/\*.txt .!`

Comment: Hi Jim and TLP, the filetype is perl

      filetype=perl

Comment: Try this and post the results `:verbose set ai? cin? cink? cino? si? inde? indk?`  Also, how are you entering the text?  Typing?  Pasting? I tried both on my system and did not get the same results as you did. The issue is probably due to some setting in your `vimrc` file.  Try searching it for keywords like "indent", "paste", or "formatoptions".

Comment: `autoindent
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
  cindent
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
  cinkeys=0{,0},0),:,0#,!^F,o,O,e
  cinoptions=
  smartindent
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
  indentexpr=
  indentkeys=0{,0},:,0#,!^F,o,O,e`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `cindent`, which is meant specifically to autoindent C code (including C-style block comments). This has no awareness that you are actually writing perl. Try `smartindent` instead, it seems to work better with perl. To try this, run `set cindent!` and then `set smartindent`. If this works better, you can change it in your .vimrc file.

If you're talking about the <kbd>=</kbd> key to indent, rather than the ident-as-you-go indentation, this is uses a separate formatter. You can change the what is used by setting `equalprg`. For perl, you might use `set equalprg=perltidy\ -quiet` to run the selected lines through `perltidy`.

Comment: Hi, I tried but it does not seem to work. When I use "=" to indent, it always take /* as comment. I think this is vim 3-piece comment format, and independent from cindent?

Comment: @PanYan You hadn't mentioned that you were using `=` to indent until just now. Updating my answer.

Comment: all your comments are correct. disabling cindent fixed  indentation while typing and `set equalprg=pertidy\ -quiet` worked for "=" key. Thanks a lot!!